# Is there any way a Chrome Extension (content script on a page) can access the cursor position in a TINYMCE editor?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tinymce

I can replace or append content to a TINYMCE editor (editor on a page, my code in a Chrome Extension content script).

But I can't seem to interact with TINYMCE apis or otherwise gain the cursor position/selection made by the user.

Goal is to add text to the existing content in the TINYMCE.

Updated with suggestion from the very generous @wOxxOm..

In my content script I've tried this - with no effect:

```
var actualCode = 'nStart = tinyMce.activeEditor.selection.getStart();console.log("Embedded code/nStart:", nStart)';  
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = actualCode;
// (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
$('#tinymce').appendChild(script);
script.remove();
```

When I used `document.body.appendChild(script);` I got:

> VM2681:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMce is not defined

Any further thoughts/direction/ideas appreciated. I'm not sure where to inject the code, or how the injected code can use the tinymce APIs. Or, since the tinymce editor is in an iframe maybe it's not about APIs but using my content code resident in that iFrame (I'm injecting into every frame).

Comment: See [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm...I updated my question...I've actually used this strategy to interact with React, but only have a vague sense what's going on...and how I can best place HTML in a tinymce editor on a page.

Comment: It means there is no global variable `tinyMce`. Type `tiny` in devtools console on that page and see what pops up. It's likely to be `tinyMCE` or `tinymce`.